Reduce latency from a software rtsp switch
I've been working on a script that uses gstreamer to create a data pipeline to switch between the cameras with moderate success because the software does what its supposed to but has a lot of input lag, having up to 3s of latency from camera to screen. Any advice on how to fix this?

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GLib
import os
import threading
import time
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import socket

os.environ['GST_DEBUG'] = '2'
os.environ['GST_BUFFER_SIZE'] = '1024'

class RTSPMultiStreamServer:
    def __init__(self, config_file="rtsp_sources.txt", port="8555"):
        Gst.init(None)
        
        self.config_file = config_file
        self.sources = []
        self.active_sources = []
        self.current_source = 0
        self.running = True
        self.pipeline = None
        self.last_switch_time = 0  # Time of last switch
        self.switch_cooldown = 1.0  # Minimum time between switches (seconds)
        self.switching = False  # Flag to prevent simultaneous switches
        
        self.verify_sources()
        
        if not self.active_sources:
            print("No active RTSP sources available")
            return
            
        self.server = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
        self.server.set_service(port)
        
        self.factory = GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory()
        self.factory.set_shared(True)
        self.factory.set_latency(0)
        
        self.factory.connect('media-configure', self.on_media_configure)
        
        self.setup_pipeline()
        mounts = self.server.get_mount_points()
        if mounts is None:
            print("Error: Could not get mount points")
            return
            
        try:
            mounts.remove_factory("/test")
        except Exception:
            pass  # Ignore if doesn't exist
            
        mounts.add_factory("/test", self.factory)
        print(f"Mount point added: /test on port {port}")

    def verify_rtsp_url(self, url, timeout=2):
        """Verifies if an RTSP stream is active"""
        try:
            # Create a simpler test pipeline
            test_pipeline_str = (
                f'rtspsrc location="{url}" latency=0 protocols=tcp ! '
                'fakesink sync=false'
            )
            
            test_pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(test_pipeline_str)
            
            # Try to play
            ret = test_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            #time.sleep(1)
            
            # Check state
            state = test_pipeline.get_state(timeout * Gst.SECOND)
            
            # Cleanup
            test_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            
            return state[0] == Gst.StateChangeReturn.SUCCESS
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error verifying {url}: {str(e)}")
            return False

    def verify_sources(self):
        """Reads and verifies all RTSP sources"""
        if not os.path.exists(self.config_file):
            with open(self.config_file, "w") as f:
                f.write("rtsp://example1.com/stream1\nrtsp://example2.com/stream2")
            print(f"File {self.config_file} created. Please add valid RTSP URLs.")
            return
            
        with open(self.config_file, "r") as f:
            self.sources = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
            
        print("\nVerifying RTSP sources...")
        for url in self.sources:
            print(f"\nVerifying {url}...", end=" ", flush=True)
            if self.verify_rtsp_url(url):
                self.active_sources.append(url)
                print("✓ ACTIVE")
            else:
                print("✗ INACTIVE")
                
        print(f"\nSources summary:")
        print(f"Total sources: {len(self.sources)}")
        print(f"Active sources: {len(self.active_sources)}")
        print(f"Inactive sources: {len(self.sources) - len(self.active_sources)}")
        
        if self.active_sources:
            print("\nActive sources:")
            for i, url in enumerate(self.active_sources, 1):
                print(f"{i}. {url}")
        
        if len(self.sources) - len(self.active_sources) > 0:
            print("\nInactive sources:")
            inactive = set(self.sources) - set(self.active_sources)
            for i, url in enumerate(inactive, 1):
                print(f"{i}. {url}")
        print()

    def setup_pipeline(self):
        """Sets up the complete pipeline with active sources"""
        if not self.active_sources:
            print("No active sources to configure pipeline")
            return

        # Create pipelines for each source
        source_pipelines = []
        for i, url in enumerate(self.active_sources):
            source_pipeline = f"""
                rtspsrc location="{url}" ! 
                decodebin ! videoconvert ! 
                videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=854,height=480 !
                queue max-size-buffers=1 ! selector.sink_{i}
            """
            source_pipelines.append(source_pipeline)

        # Selector and encoder pipeline
        output_pipeline = """
            input-selector name=selector sync-mode=0 !
            x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1000 speed-preset=ultrafast 
            key-int-max=30 vbv-buf-capacity=1000 ! 
            rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 config-interval=1
        """

        # Join all pipelines
        full_pipeline = " ".join(source_pipelines) + output_pipeline
        
        try:
            self.factory.set_launch(full_pipeline)
            self.factory.set_shared(True)
            self.factory.set_latency(0)
            
            # Connect signal to get pipeline
            self.factory.connect('media-configure', self.on_media_configure)
            
            print("Pipeline configured successfully")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error configuring pipeline: {str(e)}")

    def on_media_configure(self, factory, media):
        """Callback when media is configured"""
        self.pipeline = media.get_element()
        
        # Configure initial selector
        selector = self.pipeline.get_by_name("selector")
        if selector:
            selector.set_property("active-pad", 
                                selector.get_static_pad("sink_0"))
        return True

    def switch_source(self):
        """Switches to next source with rapid change protection"""
        if not self.active_sources or not self.pipeline:
            return False
            
        # Check if switch is in progress
        if self.switching:
            print("\nWait... switch in progress")
            return False
            
        # Check cooldown
        current_time = time.time()
        time_since_last_switch = current_time - self.last_switch_time
        
        if time_since_last_switch < self.switch_cooldown:
            remaining = round(self.switch_cooldown - time_since_last_switch, 1)
            print(f"\nWait {remaining}s to switch again")
            return False
            
        try:
            self.switching = True
            
            # Calculate next source
            next_source = (self.current_source + 1) % len(self.active_sources)
            url = self.active_sources[next_source]
            
            # Switch to next source
            selector = self.pipeline.get_by_name("selector")
            if selector:
                # Prepare switch
                next_pad = selector.get_static_pad(f"sink_{next_source}")
                if not next_pad:
                    print("\nError: Pad not found")
                    return False
                    
                # Perform switch
                selector.set_property("active-pad", next_pad)
                self.current_source = next_source
                self.last_switch_time = current_time
                
                print(f"\nSwitching to source {self.current_source + 1}/{len(self.active_sources)}: "
                      f"{self.active_sources[self.current_source]}")
                
                return True
                
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"\nError switching source: {str(e)}")
            return False
            
        finally:
            self.switching = False

    def source_switcher(self):
        while self.running:
            #time.sleep(10)
            if not self.running:
                break
            self.switch_source()

    def handle_commands(self):
        """Handles user input commands"""
        while self.running:
            try:
                command = input().strip().lower()
                if command == 'n' or command == 'next':
                    self.switch_source()
                elif command == 'l' or command == 'list':
                    self.list_sources()
                elif command == 'c' or command == 'cooldown':
                    self.show_cooldown()
                elif command == 'h' or command == 'help':
                    self.print_help()
                elif command == 'q' or command == 'quit':
                    self.running = False
                    print("\nStopping server...")
                    break
            except EOFError:
                continue
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.running = False
                print("\nStopping server...")
                break

    def list_sources(self):
        """Shows list of active sources"""
        print("\nActive sources:")
        for i, url in enumerate(self.active_sources, 1):
            if i - 1 == self.current_source:
                print(f"→ {i}. {url} (CURRENT)")
            else:
                print(f"  {i}. {url}")

    def print_help(self):
        """Shows available command help"""
        print("\nAvailable commands:")
        print("  n, next     - Switch to next stream")
        print("  l, list     - List active streams")
        print("  c, cooldown - Show remaining time to switch")
        print("  h, help     - Show this help")
        print("  q, quit     - Exit program")

    def start(self):
        if not self.active_sources:
            print("Error: No active RTSP sources")
            return False
            
        try:
            if not self.server.attach(None):
                print("Error: Could not attach server to context")
                return False
                
            print(f"\nRTSP Server started:")
            print(f"URL: rtsp://localhost:{self.server.get_service()}/test")
            print(f"Active sources in use: {len(self.active_sources)}")
            self.list_sources()
            self.print_help()
            
            # Start thread for GLib main loop
            loop = GLib.MainLoop()
            loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=loop.run)
            loop_thread.daemon = True
            loop_thread.start()
            
            # Handle commands in main thread
            self.handle_commands()
            
            # Cleanup
            loop.quit()
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error starting server: {str(e)}")
            return False
        
        return True

    def show_cooldown(self):
        """Shows remaining cooldown time"""
        time_since_last = time.time() - self.last_switch_time
        if time_since_last < self.switch_cooldown:
            remaining = round(self.switch_cooldown - time_since_last, 1)
            print(f"\nRemaining time to switch: {remaining}s")
        else:
            print("\nYou can switch sources now")

def main():
    try:
        server = RTSPMultiStreamServer(port="8555")
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nProgram terminated by user")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The idea behind the code is to be able to switch between multiple streams over a single output, but with that much lag its complicated to apply this at a real application. I'm using FPV cameras from SIYI and an Ethernet switch to transmit the stream to QGroundControl on a PC on the same network

Is the source h264, i mean you Decode, encode both without hardware accerlation, maybe decodebin autoselect a hw Decoder not sure about that also your Client needs to Decode it. So having 3 secs for this is not so Bad.

You may get more answers if you can [edit] the question and reduce the code to a [mcve] (focus on the minimal part). Did you use a profiler? What did you find? This may be hard to answer without your camera setup.

I understand your goal, but you decode,encode,Decode. When you handle Just this Client Side you would only have one decode. Like a Browser with tabs, your GUI Would handle the one view thingy
